# How to mock a function that is dynamically evaluated at runtime, using pytest-mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I have the following snippet of code from `src/myapp/requests`:

```
request_methods = {
    'GET': requests.get,
    'POST': requests.post
}

def generic_request(method, url, auth, headers, params, json)
    request_method = request_methods.get(method.upper())
    if not request_method:
        #raise some exception
    
    res = request_method(url, params=params, auth=auth, headers=headers, json=json, verify=False
    if not res.ok:
         additional_info = {'response_text': res.text}
         raise InternalServerException(additional_info=additional_info)

    return res
```

As you can see, `request_method` is determined at runtime based on the argument to `method` in `generic_request`. My question is how to do I correctly patch the `request_method` call with a stub so that it always returns a response where `ok` is False? I attempted this and it "worked":

```
def test_generic_request_bad_response_exception(mocker:MockerFixture):
    actual_request_method = 'myapp.requests.requests.get'
    mock_request_method = Mock()
    mock_request_method.return_value.ok = False
    mock_request_method.return_value.text = 'Resource does not exist'

    mocker.patch(actual_request_method, mock_request_method)
    with pytest.raises(InternalServerException) as exception_info:
        generic_request('GET', '')
    
    assert exception_info.value.additional_info.get('response_text') == 'Resource does not exist'
```

I'm not so sure this is actually doing what I think it's doing though. When I tried replacing the http method with 'POST' in the call to `generic_request`, without changing the `actual_request_method` method that I want to mock, it still "worked".

```
def test_generic_request_bad_response_exception(mocker:MockerFixture):
    actual_request_method = 'myapp.requests.requests.get'
    mock_request_method = Mock()
    mock_request_method.return_value.ok = False
    mock_request_method.return_value.text = 'Resource does not exist'
    mocker.patch(actual_request_method, mock_request_method)
    with pytest.raises(InternalServerException) as exception_info:
        generic_request('POST', '')

    assert exception_info.value.additional_info.get('response_text') == 'Resource does not exist'
```

This "passed" but it shouldn't have, right? Because I am trying to mock the `get` method at `actual_request_method = 'myapp.requests.requests.get'`, but that is not the method that will ultimately get called with `generic_request('POST', '')`. Really confused as to what is actually happening here. The assert statement at the end of the method is passing successfully so that tells me that the call to `request_method` in `generic_request` is in fact returning the mock object, I just don't understand how since the *get* method I'm trying to mock in the second scenario is ultimately not the one that should be getting called when I invoke `generic_request('POST', '')`. Please let me know if anything is unclear.